# VSCode terminal does not show all the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have imported a csv file into a pandas dataframe and it has some stock price data on it. I am trying to print all the rows on the terminal but VSCode does not let me see more than 10 lines at a time. I have pasted a screenshot below to demonstrate what I mean.

**VSCode Terminal Window:**

[image]

I have even tried adding `.head(100)` after the dataframe name to view fewer lines but it does the same thing; it just shows the lines at the beginning and at the end and puts three dots in between. I have tried all the possible solutions I could find on Google, most of them seem to be focusing around the setting I have shown on the following screenshot:

**scrollback buffer setting:**

[image]

However, changing that setting does not do anything for me. I anyone knows how to fix this issue, I will greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to **VSCode** but to **pandas DataFrame**  itself. If you set:

```
 pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 1000)
```

before printing where 1000 is the number of rows you would like to see, you will see that much rows printed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it does not seem to fix the issue. If I change the value to something lower like 5, it prints 5 lines but it shows lines 1, 2, 4 and 5 but prints three dots instead of line 3. If I set it to something high like 1000, it does not make any changes.

Comment: Did you try `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None) ` ?

Comment: I have just tried it. It prints perfectly until row 163 and then stops in the middle of row 164 with some characters missing in the rest of that row. There are about 1300 rows on the table. I had a quick look at the pandas documentation to see if there is a maximum character limit but could not see anything.

Comment: Could you also try `pd.set_option('display.max_columns' none)` together with the `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`

Comment: It expanded the number of rows a little bit but still does not display more than half of the file. I have also just realized the index numbers go back to 0 zero in every 90-100 rows.

Comment: Interesting, I would suggest Jupyter notebooks for VSCode for better print results  (and immediate feedback of your code) until you solve that problem. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Comment: Thank you for the help and your time.